# How to return comma delimited string from array, in React, javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have array like this

```
const users = [{
  "name": "John",
  "color": "blue",
},{
  "name": "Tim",
  "color": "red",
},{
  "name": "Mike",
  "color": "green",
}]
```

I want to return result as

```
str = "John",Tim","Mike"
```

but when I use

```
const str = users.map(item => item.name).join(', ');
```

I'm getting like this

```
str = "John,Tim,Mike"
```

Comment: Do you mean you literally want `"John","Tim","Mike"` in the actual variable value?

Comment: Yes I want "John","Tim","Mike" Instead of "John,Tim,Mike"  @Terry

Comment: `const str = \`"${users.map(x => x.name).join('", "')}"\`;`

Comment: Does this give you the desired result?: ```const str = users.map(item => `"${item.name}"`).join(', ');```

Comment: @sss added as an answer, with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
const str = `"${users.map(x => x.name).join('", "')}"`;
```

Which uses a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to give the leading and trailing quotes with the joined array inbetween. Ungolfed:

```js
let str = '"'; // prepend "
str += users
  .map(x => x.name) // get the name from the user objs
  .join('", "') // join with the double quote and comma

str += '"'; // closing "
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a reduce function as that is used to reduce an array to a single output. If it is the first item (index == 0), then just return the name to the accumulator (which kind of stores the string and appends to it as you go through the array) with quotation marks on either side (escaped with \ but not necessary if using single quotes), else return the accumulator with a comma and a quotation mark after it as well as the name and another quotation mark.

So as you go through the array, the accumulator will be something like this:

- 
- "John"
- "John","Tim"
- "John","Tim","Mike"

and when it gets to the end, it returns it to the variable, so `commaSeparatedString == "\"John\",\"Tim\",\"Mike\""`

```js
const users = [{
  "name": "John",
  "color": "blue",
}, {
  "name": "Tim",
  "color": "red",
}, {
  "name": "Mike",
  "color": "green",
}];


const commaSeparatedString = users.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, index) {
  return index == 0 
    ? '\"' + currentValue.name + '\"'
    : accumulator + ',\"' + currentValue.name + '\"';
}, '');

console.log(commaSeparatedString);
```

Comment: You can simply it quite a bit: `users.reduce((acc, {name}) => acc ? \`${acc}, "${name}"\` : \`"${name}"\`, '')`. Since the empty string is falsey you can check the accumulator value instead of needing the index, and you can use destructuring to pull out the name.

Comment: Nice, thanks for that @JaredSmith, that is a lot cleaner!